# Does html5 local storage store per iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, local-storage

If I have a page A, and it loads several iframes B,C,D,E,F. And in each iframe, there is javascript code that stores a key `color` with value `red` in local storage. Will all the iframes local storage collide or is each one independent? If it is not independent, is there a way to make it independent?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

According to [the W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp):

> Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

In other words, if the iframes all reside in the same domain, then they will share the same local storage instance.

One way to potentially avoid collisions would be to use the current page URL as a key into a local storage dictionary, something like:

```
localStorage.setItem(window.location.pathname + "_color", "red");
```

Comment: I agree with your way to avoid collision, but I feel like window.location.origin would be a better prefix.