# Iframe chrome : Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JavaScript widget. I have used localstorage for setting and getting properties of the `window`.

When I open that widget in Chrome it throws an error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

If I allow third party cookies in the browser it's working properly. The problem is that I cannot allow third parties cookies of every user manually. What is a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You should consider to use this browser API instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Since the local storage is only related **to the specific domain**, so it can not be used across different domains.

For example: if the iframe domain is "www.aaa.com" and page domain is "www.bbb.com", the iframe can not access to the page related local storage. No problem if they are in the same domain.

A complete explanation about this argument can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: What if you do not control the parent domain, would I have to use something other than localStorage?

Comment: Good followup question.  I don't see why a cross domain iframe cannot access its own localStorage.  It should only be a security issue to access the localStorage of the parent domain.  postMessage is nothing to do with localStorage

Comment: @Phil, because there is no "iframe localStorage", it is origin-based. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34002337/8534482